# MVC Spring Java - display picture stored as field in the class

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have a class Car with fields id, brand and image stored as String which I am preloading after running the app:

repository.save(new Car("ford", "fiesta", 23.0, "../img/car.jpg", "data"));

Now I am storing the object in the list and adding the class as model to a thymeleaf template and I want to display it in a loop with the connected image:

```
 <li th:each="car: ${cars}">
    <p th:text="'Id: ' + ${car.id}"/>
    <p th:text="'Brand: ' + ${car.brand }"/>
    <p th:src="'image' + ${car.imageLink }"/>
</li>
```

The id and brand are stored correctly, but the image is not displayed. The directory structure is as follows: [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9uK.png) How can I change it to display the picture on the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<img src="../static/img/car.jpg" width="1000" th:src="@{img/car.jpg}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for displaying the picture directly, but the loop should display it from the link "img/car.jpg" stored in the class like this:
        <p><img width="500" th:src="@{car.imageLink}"/></p>